# Heroku Application Error - despite successful deploy

Tags: python, flask, heroku, deployment, application-error

**Background:**
I have a Flask app with RESTful API and webpages that I'm trying to deploy to Heroku. As a Python-based (app.py) project, I obviously deploy the 'python way'. The requirements include a `requirements.txt` file.

**Issue:**
I did a `pip freeze` and had a tonne of libraries fill my Terminal. I figured 'what the heck, I'll copy the entire contents to a `requirements.txt` (and yes, I spelt it correctly!) and save in the root dir of my project, alongside my `main.py` file.
Whilst Heroku is deploying, it installs the requirements etc and **says the app is deployed successfully**, however when I navigate to my project, I'm given a Heroku generic 'Application Error' message ([here](https://project-2-website.herokuapp.com)).
**USEFUL INFO:**

**Logs:** for my most recent build attempt -

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Requirements file has been changed, clearing cached dependencies
-----> Installing python-3.6.12
-----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       Collecting Flask==1.1.2
         Downloading Flask-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
       Collecting Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
         Downloading Flask-Bootstrap-3.3.7.1.tar.gz (456 kB)
       Collecting flask-marshmallow==0.13.0
         Downloading flask_marshmallow-0.13.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.9 kB)
       Collecting Flask-PyMongo==2.3.0
         Downloading Flask_PyMongo-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
       Collecting Flask-RESTful==0.3.8
         Downloading Flask_RESTful-0.3.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
       Collecting Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
         Downloading Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
       Collecting flaskerizer==0.0.8
         Downloading flaskerizer-0.0.8.tar.gz (17 kB)
       Collecting pymongo==3.11.0
         Downloading pymongo-3.11.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (508 kB)
       Collecting json2html==1.3.0
         Downloading json2html-1.3.0.tar.gz (7.0 kB)
       Collecting json5==0.9.5
         Downloading json5-0.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
       Collecting beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
         Downloading beautifulsoup4-4.9.1-py3-none-any.whl (115 kB)
       Collecting Jinja2>=2.10.1
         Downloading Jinja2-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
       Collecting itsdangerous>=0.24
         Downloading itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
       Collecting click>=5.1
         Downloading click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
       Collecting Werkzeug>=0.15
         Downloading Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
       Collecting dominate
         Downloading dominate-2.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
       Collecting visitor
         Downloading visitor-0.1.3.tar.gz (3.3 kB)
       Collecting marshmallow>=2.0.0
         Downloading marshmallow-3.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (45 kB)
       Collecting six>=1.9.0
         Downloading six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
       Collecting aniso8601>=0.82
         Downloading aniso8601-8.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
       Collecting pytz
         Downloading pytz-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
       Collecting SQLAlchemy>=0.8.0
         Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.3.19-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.3 MB)
       Collecting numpy
         Downloading numpy-1.19.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (14.5 MB)
       Collecting soupsieve>1.2
         Downloading soupsieve-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (32 kB)
       Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23
         Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (27 kB)
       Building wheels for collected packages: Flask-Bootstrap, flaskerizer, json2html, visitor
         Building wheel for Flask-Bootstrap (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for Flask-Bootstrap (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for Flask-Bootstrap: filename=Flask_Bootstrap-3.3.7.1-py3-none-any.whl size=460123 sha256=9bd9e63bb6b77d2a2750200e52bb64f47e327c55fcf5d53e56273422c6897236
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-n6hu4_1p/wheels/5b/f4/4f/26886e9f06b0c1b6d54104a1fb423ebc7e06d94cf69700348e
         Building wheel for flaskerizer (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for flaskerizer (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for flaskerizer: filename=flaskerizer-0.0.8-py3-none-any.whl size=19420 sha256=651ddb678fae4fa5961d8a95cab2569b2b8a3adefed4440b80fb3bba26a95aa7
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-n6hu4_1p/wheels/cc/1d/54/3c80ed968fd156ae6a6b44923127522538f8ade767dbd8d256
         Building wheel for json2html (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for json2html (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for json2html: filename=json2html-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl size=7596 sha256=cab0c712dd167dda857c2fa995b731fc5be5644adcd3a4425a8d8a33da05749e
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-n6hu4_1p/wheels/ac/31/34/ddfd5ecba08389f839470d849288be216fcb22f1403eaa05df
         Building wheel for visitor (setup.py): started
         Building wheel for visitor (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
         Created wheel for visitor: filename=visitor-0.1.3-py3-none-any.whl size=3931 sha256=4ae43104c4bd7035ce0d468ea846a663c66444810b67338ef9df91be7245bcf8
         Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-n6hu4_1p/wheels/a9/77/93/3b8a22ac46f57a22d0fd7b4912fff740bcbddbd720bd48508e
       Successfully built Flask-Bootstrap flaskerizer json2html visitor
       Installing collected packages: MarkupSafe, Jinja2, itsdangerous, click, Werkzeug, Flask, dominate, visitor, Flask-Bootstrap, marshmallow, six, flask-marshmallow, pymongo, Flask-PyMongo, aniso8601, pytz, Flask-RESTful, SQLAlchemy, Flask-SQLAlchemy, numpy, flaskerizer, json2html, json5, soupsieve, beautifulsoup4
       Successfully installed Flask-1.1.2 Flask-Bootstrap-3.3.7.1 Flask-PyMongo-2.3.0 Flask-RESTful-0.3.8 Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.4.4 Jinja2-2.11.2 MarkupSafe-1.1.1 SQLAlchemy-1.3.19 Werkzeug-1.0.1 aniso8601-8.0.0 beautifulsoup4-4.9.1 click-7.1.2 dominate-2.5.1 flask-marshmallow-0.13.0 flaskerizer-0.0.8 itsdangerous-1.1.0 json2html-1.3.0 json5-0.9.5 marshmallow-3.7.1 numpy-1.19.1 pymongo-3.11.0 pytz-2020.1 six-1.15.0 soupsieve-2.0.1 visitor-0.1.3
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 75.5M
-----> Launching...
       Released v7
       https://project-2-website.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

**Flask code:**

```
import flask
from flask import Flask, jsonify, Response, render_template
from flask import redirect
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson import ObjectId, json_util
import json

cluster = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://USERNAME:PASSWORD@cluster0.mpjcg.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = cluster["simply_recipe"]
collection = db["recipes_collection"]

app = Flask(__name__)

# This route returns the team's index page
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

# This route returns heesung's plot page of the team's website
@app.route("/heesung/")
def heesung():
    return redirect("https://heesung80.github.io/recipe/")

# This route returns caitlin's plot page of the team's website
@app.route("/caitlin")
def caitlin_plots():
    return render_template('inner-page_caitlin.html')

# This route returns all the recipe_collection data in JSON.
@app.route("/recipes", methods=["GET"])
def get_recipes():
    all_recipes = list(collection.find({}))
    return json.dumps(all_recipes, default=json_util.default)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Does anyone have any suggestions, why my Flask app deploys successfully, but gives the Application Error?

Answer (score 0):

You have included your build logs, but what does it say in your application logs? The `logs` command retrieves 100 log lines by default so visit your app in a browser then run this in your terminal: `heroku logs -a name-of-your-app` (or [view logs from the UI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-retrieval-via-the-web-dashboard)). That should hopefully give you a better error to look up. To view logs easier, you should add a logging add-on to the app ([Papertrail has a free plan](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/papertrail) you can use).

Without looking at your logs, I'd guess it's an issue with establishing your connection with MongoDB. I can't tell where the values for `USERNAME`, `PASSWORD` and `<dbname>` are coming from for `"mongodb+srv://USERNAME:PASSWORD@cluster0.mpjcg.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority"` but since you are using `+srv`, I assume you are using MongoDB Atlas. I don't have experience with this myself but the docs indicate you need to [whitelist IPs](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-whitelist/) to establish a connection. If your app is in Private Spaces, you can just whitelist [your space's outbound IPs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/private-spaces#view-information-about-a-private-space) with Mongo, but if the app is in Common Runtime, you will need to whitelist `0.0.0.0/0` as Common Runtime does not have static outbound IPs.

Your connection string should also be set as a [config var](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) on the app.

Answer (score 0):

Having taken the advice from the comments and online research I noticed that when you deploy to Heroku, Heroku tried to build my environment using the `Pipfile`, rather than the `Procfile`.

**Solution:**
by deleting the `Pipfile`, Heroku fell back to using `Procfile` which ensured by build and deploy was successful.